# retrieving the results of a reentrant lexing without file i/o

Tags: c++, c, flex-lexer

I have a flex module in a C++ project that I want to call from multiple threads.
My .lex file's options include stack and reentrant.
Assuming that it is possible to call yylex on different scanner objects from different threads simultaneously and not have one lexing sequence block the other (which I *think* is the case but i'm not entirely sure), how do I recover the output for each of these? The only facility I see for this is yyset_out(FILE* handle, yyscan_t scanner), but I don't want to have to have to use files because I only want the results of the lexing without having to do a file write.

I set the input with:

```
void scanProcedure(...threadInfo...) {
   yyscan_t tscanner;

   yylex_init(tscanner);
   yy_scan_string(threadInfo->lexMe, tscanner);
   yylex(tscanner);

   /* how to retrieve results of lexing in a 
      reentrant manner ( no global state info ) 
      without having to do any file i/o */

   /* threadInfo-> ?? */

   yylex_destroy(tscanner);
}

...

pthread_create( ... scanProcedure ... threadInfoA ... );
pthread_create( ... scanProcedure ... threadInfoB ... );
pthread_create( ... scanProcedure ... threadInfoC ... );

pthread_join( ... );
```

Also, I realize that I could call yyset_out on a temporary file and then access the file buffer but it seems to me as though there should be a prettier (less hackish) solution than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're using the default output, it goes to a FILE, but there's no need to do that --you can just write your actions to send the output to anywhere you want.  You can define your own `YY_EXTRA_TYPE` data structure and use yyget_extra/yyset_extra to manipulate it, if you need some extra per-scanner state to keep track of where the output is going.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the Flex manual Accessor Methods chapter](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Accessor-Methods.html)